# some question about Qt Creator widget

Tags: qt-creator

could you help me?

First:
How can I make the size of main window in Qt Creator fixed,so users can not maximize?. I set resize propriety to ( fixed ) but I still run the project and maximize it .

Second:
How can keep ToolBar fixed in one location? I do not want change its location by users.

Third:
How can make an item in QMenu Not checkable if another item is check? Like radioButton and make one item as default.

Thank you in Advance.

Answer (score 1):

First: apply the same size to maximumSize and minimumSize (`window->setMinimumSize(size)`, `window->setMaximumSize(size)`)

Second: use the QToolBar's setMovable() method: `toolbar->setMovable(false);`

Third: Implement a slot that listens to the action's `changed()` signal, and calls the other action's setCheckable() method, passing false as an argument: `actionToBeDisabled->setCheckable(false);`

Comment: Thank you for your answer .first and second work correctly but third did not work? I tried to use triggered() signal but same thing (each item was checked).

Comment: Sorry, it looks like triggered() is the way to go. But not QMenu::triggered(), but QAction::triggered(), because QMenu::triggered() will be emitted every time any action is selected.